# URL.createObjectURL which is not outdated

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Currently I'm trying to learn more about fetch, promises and overall API. I came across this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc8DU14qX6I&
but he is using `URL.createObjectURL()` which didn't work for me and  Google told me that this method is not supported by browsers anymore. So can someone explain to me how to rewrite this code to get correct results? Also do you have any recommendations where to learn more in this subject?

```
<img src="" id="rainbow" />

    <script>

        fetch('rainbow.png').then(response => {
            return response.blob();
        }).then(blob => {
            console.log(blob);
            document.getElementById('rainbow').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Deprecated? It's not even in the standard yet. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: Oh i see, it just didnt work for me and ive seen comment "URL.createObjectURL() doesn't work in chrome anymore." so i thought its deprecated. Thank you.